# PHP: Fill array values with corrosponding keys from html meta tags

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a folder of HTML files, each with meta tags that include dates. I would like to fetch the list of URL's read each one's date meta tag, and finally print the list in order from oldest to youngest, or perhaps youngest to oldest.

I am a beginner at PHP, so I have been able to do a lot of the work myself, but I can't seem to put the various pieces together.

To get a list of the files' URL's into an array is easy enough:

```
$list = glob('path/*.html');
```

To fetch the date tag for each individual file is also easy:

```
$tags=get_meta_tags($file_url);
$date = $tags['date'];
```

And I can easily sort the array by key using `ksort($list);` or `krsort($list);`

However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to put this together so that I create a list of URL's, each one with a key from its own date meta tag, and then sort that list.

Any help would be much appreciated, but please keep in mind that I am a complete, absolute beginner at PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$list = glob('path/*.html');
foreach ($list as $file) {
  $tags=get_meta_tags($file);
  $result[$tags['date']] = $file;
}
ksort($result);
?>
```

It computes an array of files using the dates as keys which the list is sorted by.

Comment: You don't perhaps know if there is by any chance some way to achieve this **without** using a foreach() loop?